# Changing a continuous scale from decimal to percents

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, missing-data

The scale for penetration is listed as a decimal (.5 and down), but I am having a problem changing it to a percent.

I tried to format it in my data as a percentage using this code

```
penetration_levels$Penetration<-sprintf("%.1f %%", 100*penetration_levels$Penetration)
```

which worked from a format sense, but when I tried to graph the plot I got an error saying penetration was used as a discrete, not continuous scale.

To fix that, used this code to format it as a numeric variable

```
penetration_levels$Penetration<-as.numeric(as.character(penetration_levels$Penetration))
```

Which returned a bunch of `NA`s.  Does anyone know any other method of how I can change it to a percent?

Here is the code I used to map

ggplot code:

```
map <- ggplot(penetration_levels,aes(long,lat,group=region,fill=Penetration),) + geom_polygon() + coord _equal() + scale_fill_gradient2(low="red",mid="white",high="green",midpoint=.25)
map <- map + geom_point(data=mydata, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=1,fill=0, size=Annualized.Opportunity), color="gray6") + scale_size(name="Total Annual Opportunity-Millions",range=c(2,4))  
map <- map + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12,face="bold"))
map
```

Head of mydata and penetration

```
head(mydata)
Sold.To.Customer            City State Annualized.Opportunity           location          lat      long
21          10000110        NEW YORK    NY              12.142579        NEW YORK,NY     40.71435 -74.00597
262         10016487 FORT LAUDERDALE    FL              12.087310 FORT LAUDERDALE,FL 26.12244 -80.13732
349         11001422      ALLEN PARK    MI              10.910575      ALLEN PARK,MI 42.25754 -83.21104
19          10000096           ALTON    IL              10.040067           ALTON,IL 38.89060 -90.18428
477         11067228        BAY CITY    TX              10.030829        BAY CITY,TX 28.98276 -95.96940
230         10014909        BETHPAGE    NY               9.320271        BETHPAGE,NY 40.74427 -73.48207
```

```
head(penetration_levels)
State  region      long      lat group order subregion state       To     From    Total    Penetration
17    AL alabama -87.46201 30.38968     1     1      <NA>    AL 10794947 12537359 23332307    0.462661
18    AL alabama -87.48493 30.37249     1     2      <NA>    AL 10794947 12537359 23332307    0.462661
22    AL alabama -87.52503 30.37249     1     3      <NA>    AL 10794947 12537359 23332307    0.462661
36    AL alabama -87.53076 30.33239     1     4      <NA>    AL 10794947 12537359 23332307    0.462661
37    AL alabama -87.57087 30.32665     1     5      <NA>    AL 10794947 12537359 23332307    0.462661
65    AL alabama -87.58806 30.32665     1     6      <NA>    AL 10794947 12537359 23332307    0.462661
```

I also just noticed that there was a white strip, similar to a polygon that is missing in Washington… do you happen to know why that is?  I tried to re-merge my data and order it again, but still the same result.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Map]

Also, I noticed that Washington has a white polygon missing? Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I've had a similar problem with Washington having a diagonal line through it.  When I've deleted Alaska from your penetration_levels data set, it's gone away

Comment: You may search for 'percent' [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html) and you will find an example.

Comment: Huh.  So Alaska is the problem.  I may have to try to find a different spatial background then.

Comment: @Henrik: Right, but then again the use of a function for the `labels` argument is not documented [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/continuous_scale.html)...

Comment: @krlmlr, Sorry, I don't follow you. Compare `p` (y labels from 0.00 to 1.00) and `p + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)` (y labels from 0% to 100%).

Comment: @Henrik: The docs read: "labels: NULL for no labels, waiver() for default labels (labels the same as breaks), a character vector the same length as breaks, or a named character vector whose names are used to match replacement the labels for matching breaks." They don't say that you can also use a function for the `labels` parameter, and `percent` is a function defined in the `scales` package.

Comment: I agree that it is poorly documented in the argument section. That's why I pointed to **the example ("search for 'percent'")**, where `library(scales)` is mentioned.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I actually tried this earlier, but didn't have the scales library loaded.  Pretty mad at myself for missing that, but happy the answer is resolved.  If you post the answer, Ill accept it in the am

Comment: Thanks again,  I looked at the code for hours today and could not figure it out!

Comment: Unfortunately, the `ggplot` documentation is not always as thorough as you might hope. I have spent some time scrolling through [**the output of the examples**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/)... I posted a small answer, as you asked for. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may load the `scales` package and use `scale_fill_continuous(labels = percent)`. The percent argument is not very well documented in the argument section of the help text, but an example of this function, and other convenient formats from the `scales` package, can be found in the example section [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html).

A small example:

```
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(long = 1:10, lat = 1:10,
                 penetration = seq(from = 0.1, to = 1, by = 0.1))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = penetration)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 6) +
  scale_fill_continuous(labels = percent)
```

[image]